# Missing console tab in Git toolbar

Tags: jetbrains-ide

My **Git** toolbar has no **console** tab, How can I add it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Console tab will show automatically after you execute any Git command-related operation. So you could try a Git operation like `Git | Fetch` from the main menu. The IDE will show the Console tab after that.